# Kafka broker shuts down after running for a short while

Tags: centos, apache-kafka

Kafka shuts down without error after a certain time interval.

kafka server log:

```
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,435] INFO Verifying properties (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,489] INFO Property broker.id is overridden to 0 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,489] INFO Property host.name is overridden to 172.16.1.22 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,490] INFO Property log.cleaner.enable is overridden to false (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,490] INFO Property log.dirs is overridden to /data/www/wifiin/logs/kafka (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,490] INFO Property log.retention.check.interval.ms is overridden to 300000 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,491] INFO Property log.retention.hours is overridden to 168 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,491] INFO Property log.segment.bytes is overridden to 1073741824 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,491] INFO Property num.io.threads is overridden to 8 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,491] INFO Property num.network.threads is overridden to 3 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,492] INFO Property num.partitions is overridden to 1 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,492] INFO Property num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir is overridden to 1 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,492] INFO Property port is overridden to 9092 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,493] INFO Property socket.receive.buffer.bytes is overridden to 102400 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,493] INFO Property socket.request.max.bytes is overridden to 104857600 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,493] INFO Property socket.send.buffer.bytes is overridden to 102400 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,493] INFO Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 127.0.0.1:2181 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,494] INFO Property zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms is overridden to 6000 (kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,550] INFO [Kafka Server 0], starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,553] INFO [Kafka Server 0], Connecting to zookeeper on 127.0.0.1:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,568] INFO Starting ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,579] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,579] INFO Client environment:host.name=wifiin-analysis-22 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,579] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_40 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,579] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,579] INFO Client environment:java.home=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/jre 
(org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
...
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,580] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,580] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA(org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,580] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,580] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,580] INFO Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,580] INFO Client environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,580] INFO Client environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 12:15:06,580] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/usr/local/kafka (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
...[2016-01-11 12:15:17,515] INFO [Kafka Server 0], started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-01-11 12:15:17,795] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions [sdkLog,0] (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2016-01-11 12:15:17,856] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] Removed fetcher for partitions [sdkLog,0] (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2016-01-11 14:47:41,816] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-01-11 14:47:41,818] INFO [Kafka Server 0], Starting controlled shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-01-11 14:47:41,981] INFO [Kafka Server 0], Controlled shutdown succeeded (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2016-01-11 14:47:41,983] INFO Closing socket connection to /172.16.1.22. (kafka.network.Processor)
[2016-01-11 14:47:41,984] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Shutting down (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2016-01-11 14:47:41,989] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Shutdown completed (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2016-01-11 14:47:41,991] INFO [Kafka Request Handler on Broker 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandlerPool)
[2016-01-11 14:47:41,994] INFO [Kafka Request Handler on Broker 0], shut down completely (kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandlerPool)
[2016-01-11 14:47:42,267] INFO [Replica Manager on Broker 0]: Shut down (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2016-01-11 14:47:42,267] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] shutting down (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2016-01-11 14:47:42,269] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] shutdown completed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2016-01-11 14:47:42,314] INFO [Replica Manager on Broker 0]: Shut down 
completely (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2016-01-11 14:47:42,315] INFO Shutting down. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-01-11 14:47:42,376] INFO Shutdown complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2016-01-11 14:47:42,384] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. 
(org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2016-01-11 14:47:42,396] INFO Session: 0x15210b1e3051357 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2016-01-11 14:47:42,396] INFO EventThread shut down (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2016-01-11 14:47:42,396] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

At first, I believed OutOfMemory led to the shutdown, so I edited kafka's oom_score wihtout luck.What should I do to keep the Kafka broker from shutting down?

Answer (score -1):

```
./kafka-server-start.sh -daemon ../config/server.properties
```

This may help you！